# Sobolev bound on convolution function

Tags: sobolev-spaces, convolution, positive-definite

Let $v:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$ be smooth enough and compactly supported on $B(0,1)$. Let $\delta>0$ be a scaling parameter. Assume $v_\delta=v(\cdot/\delta)$. Let $u$ be smooth enough too. I want to prove the following inequality 
$$
\|u*v_\delta\|_{H^{\beta}(\mathbb R^d)}\leq C\delta^\alpha \|u*v_\delta\|_{H^{\beta+\alpha}(\mathbb R^d)}
$$
I am not in general sure that this inequality is true or not! We can also assume that $v$ is positive definite on $\mathbb R^d$, if it is required.

Comment: Are you sure the inequality is correctly written?

Comment: It is clearly true for $\delta \geq 1$. The main point concerns the case $\delta <1$. The inequality seems to be sensible because the norm on the left hand side is smaller than the the norm on the right hand side and the factor $\delta^\alpha$ makes the inequality sharper.

Comment: Why $\delta^\alpha$? because the additional $\alpha$ derivatives will apply on $v(\cdot/\delta)$ and the scaling should produce a factor $\delta^{-\alpha}$.